# Help in sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
ID  Title   Date
30   1     10/10/2010
20   1     10/11/2010
40   2     01/01/2010
```

i need a way to select distinct titles with max dates.
so when title is 1, i should have the second row selected since the date in the 1st row is smaller than the date in the second row.
as a result the query should return:

```
20 1 10/11/2010
40 2 01/01/2010
```

Comment: Don't you mean 30 1 10/11/2010 ?

Comment: Your results set shows the ID of the first row with the date of the second.  Is this what you want or a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/sql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data set is unclear; do you want the minimum ID and the maximum date?

```
SELECT ID=MIN(ID), Title, [Date] = MAX([Date])
FROM Table
GROUP By Title
```

Or was it a typo, and you want the row with the maximum date (assuming that the dates may not follow the ID value)?

```
SELECT  a.ID
      , a.Title
      , a.Dt
FROM    Table a
        JOIN ( SELECT   b.Title
                      , Dt = MAX(Dt)
               FROM     Table b
               GROUP BY Title
             ) c ON a.Dt = c.Dt
                    AND a.Title = c.Title
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(ID) as ID, max(Date), Title
from table
group by Title
```

should do the trick

Comment: This is valid for the data sample but breaks when the max date isn't on the row with the max id

Comment: but its not always true that the largest id have the largest date.... i will edit the table...

Answer (score 0):

```
select
max(ID), Title , max(Date)
from
table
group by
Title
```

Comment: This won't work; you're grouping by the ID and the Title, which means all rows will be returned (assuming that the ID is unique).

Comment: grouping by the ID which is unique will result in returning all rows

Comment: Still not quite there :)  You have to do something with the ID column now.  Either GROUP with it, or use it in an aggregate.